# copying data from 2 files into 1 files and performing comparison

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have 3 text files , the first one has these data :

```
qry> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/2-OutputPlatesTest/20150615_062605.154_0_Front.Frontview.png
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_061434.465_0_Front.Frontview.png       

qry> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/2-OutputPlatesTest/20150615_062606.990_0_Front.Frontview.png
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_054413.737_0_Front.Frontview.png
```

Second one has all the data of the qry :

```
20150615_060636.255_0_Front.Frontview.png,,1461584960,AZ694HR
20150615_054400.428_0_Front.Frontview.png,,1461585426,BG018BH
20150615_065249.543_0_Front.Frontview.png,,1461585036,A0563BC
```

The third has all the data for the cls

```
20150612_060101.766_0_Front.Frontview.png,,1461671421,CF765MP
20150612_073132.634_0_Front.Frontview.png,,1461669509,DR06
20150612_090622.440_0_Front.Frontview.png,,1461670755,BE555GB
```

is there is an easy way to open the second file and the third file and copy the annotation characters to the first file so that  the first file will be looking like this

```
qry> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/2-OutputPlatesTest/20150615_062606.990_0_Front.Frontview.png AS776HX
cls> /opt/ADL_db/Users/mkhalil/PipeLineWork/1-OutputPlatesReference/20150612_054413.737_0_Front.Frontview.png  BQ851ZE
```

Comment: It would help if you posted relevant data set. The final output has annotations that are present in neither of the two support files.

Comment: Right. Make sure the expected output you post is precisely the output you want to get given the input you posted, not output you'd get from some other input files. You'll want to make this as simple/easy as possible for us to understand if you want us to invest time/effort into helping you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cat second.txt third.txt | while read line; do
  key=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1`
  value=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f4`
  sed -i "s/$key/$key $value/" first.txt
done
```

It's not effective for big data files but if you have only small files (especially the `first.txt` one), it should work for you. Maybe some more escaping/tuning will be required.